# How to stop night mode in android from changing color?

Tags: android, view, colors, themes, paint

I am developing a paint app for android by extending the View class. On onDraw method, I am drawing the background using canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE) each time onDraw is called and drawing other stuffs on top of it.. Everything is working fine when I am in default light theme but as soon as dark theme is applied to the device, the background of my custom view is changed to black. How can I stop this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your app's theme does not inherit from `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight` rather inherits from `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light` or some version of it to disable night more. If you need to use `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight` theme, then you can specify the a color on `values/colors.xml` and `values-night/colors.xml`. The app will use `values-night/colors.xml` colors for night theme.

Comment: <resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
          [[.[primary colors..]] </style>
</resources>
This is my theme and I have deleted themes-night.xml too.. But it still isn't working..

Answer (score 0):

Set background color to your custom view don't leave it to the default color. Android changes the default color on theme change.

> 

another solution is to set the theme to

```
<style name="App.Theme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge">
```

but this will lead to always light theme regardless of the system/phone theme.

Comment: How do I change the default color of my custom view? Setting the theme didn't work.. I changed the parent theme in themes.xml (night) too. But it still isn't working?

Comment: if you don't want night mode try removing the theme.xml(night)

Comment: I removed theme.xml(night) and it still isn't working..